# How to update the html code of current tab in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to write an extension which replaces every occurrence of some words with another word. To be able to do this, first I get the URL of the current tab, and get the content of the URL, then I replace the words. Now I want to replace the html code with the one that I updated. How can I do this? Is it a logical way to get the content, and replace the words, then reload the page? Or should I change my logic?

I've the following code so far;

```
function httpGet(theUrl, callback){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, true );
  xmlhttp.send();
}


window.onload = function(){
   chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
     httpGet(tab.url,function(result) {
          updatedContent  = result.replace(/cat/g, 'dog');
          //how will I set updatedContent to the current tab?
      });

   });
}
```

edit: 
I create an html element with updated content as;

```
var content = document.createElement('html');
content.innerHTML = updatedContent;
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
   file: content + ".html"
});
```

manifest.json;

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Replacer",
  "description": "Replacer",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
 "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"

  ]
}
```

Comment: hint: look into chrome content scripts and javascript injection :)

Comment: Yes I looked at it and add some code but still couldn't achieve. I will update the question. I will be grateful if you help me.

Comment: no problem! can you also add your manifest.json?

Comment: @NoamHacker I updated :) sure. now I will add my manifest

Comment: @NoamHacker added my manifest

Comment: thanks! what is the result currently? are you getting errors?